# IP packets does not respect ip rule

Tags: linux, networking, route, ip-routing

I'm running Linux and have the following `ip rules`

```
ip rule list
0:  from all lookup local 
150:    from 217.31.55.96/28 lookup custom 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

This is for catching all IP packets coming with source IP `217.31.55.96/28`.

I've got the following `ip route list`:

```
default via 10.8.32.254 dev eth1.vlan10  metric 10 
default via 217.31.55.110 dev eth1.vlan20  metric 20
```

and `ip route show table custom`:

```
default via 217.31.55.110 dev eth1.vlan20
```

This is for making sure that all these packets are send out via `217.31.55.110 dev eth1.vlan20`.

Doing a trace on eth1.vlan10 however shows packets with source IP within range 217.31.55.96/28 are still being sent out via the first default route on `eth1.vlan10`.

How can I fix this, and still keep all other packets using `eth1.vlan10`?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the route cache?

Comment: I rebooted the device multiple times during testing, and also restarted network services. Are there other ways to clear cache?